# Exclude primary key in model in .NET Core as SQL generates PK when INSERT

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a simple table `Tags` in my SQL Server database:

```
Tags
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255)  
)
```

So for now I want to have the corresponding model in my .NET Core Web API:

Tags.cs:

```
public partial class Tags
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Tags(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

If I am right, SQL Server should autoincrement the ID when inserting an item into table `Tags`.

How can I support this without having `ID` as an additional property in my model?

I also tried the data annotation for generated values on add
`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`. But this won't work if I want to create a new model like:

```
Tags test = new Tags("test");
```

With an ID parameter in my  model I would always need to send an additional int which I don't use when calling the constructor.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the Id as a property of your model? Id is quite convenient when updating or deleting..

Comment: then I would have to use an additional int as paremeter for the models constructor as I only want to create a model object from one string. Already stated above

Comment: I see your point for updating or deleting entries with ID, but how can I combine this when I want to create a new Object only from one string which I then would add in TagContext.Add(NewTag)?

Comment: Just add Id property tou your model, no need to set the value for Id prop in the constructor.

Comment: Is the `tag` unique: if yes then no need for `ID`, make `tag` your PK; if no, then you need `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried now following code inside my model for ID property:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

For now it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Your Tags class should have an Id property, otherwise you can't distinguish Tags with the same name. If Name is unique, you could consider not adding an ID at all and make Name the primary key, but I wouldn't recommend this.

To support this:

```
Tags test = new Tags("test");
```

you could simply create two constructors, one to initialize new Tags to store and one to construct existing tags.

```
public Tags(string name)
{
    Name = name;
}

public Tags(int id, string name)
{
    Id = id;
    Name = name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is still the problem when adding a new Tag entry to the SQL Table. The handling of parameter ID is done by the SQL Server, so I cannot just create a new Tags Object with ID and name and call `TagsContext.Add(NewTag)`.
Am I right?

Comment: this doesn't stick to my initial question, how to handle the insert with my model properties